# Performance/Operating Principle of TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

This question seems to be trivial, but I wonder why running some applications by TeamCity is so much faster than running it local triggered.
Does there exist any special operating principle (multithreading?) ?

Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: can you give specific examples? In general out of the box nothing runs really in parallel on TeamCity (unless you specifically take advantage of tasks that can be broken down and assigned to multiple agents)

Comment: I've just recognized that a simple executable, which is developed by VisualStudio and which e.g.: processes some data, runs much faster with TeamCity than if you run it manually.
So, I'm wondering what's the reason for that.

Comment: most likely machine specs then